# Python3 utf-8 decoding/encoding problems with data hiding

Tags: python-3.x, byte, decode, encode, steganography

I'm trying to take the text from a file (the text is Russian), hide it in an image, and then later be able to retrieve it from the image. However, I keep getting `binascii.Error: Odd-length string` when I try to retrieve the data from the image I hid it in.

I feel like the problem may lie within what I use to hide the text. When I do `someString = file.read()` on the file, and print `someString` everything comes out fine. But when I run:

`file = open(<text file path>, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
 entireText = file.read()
 print(codecs.encode(entireText,'utf-8'))`

I get the following:

```
b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2:\n\xd0\x9e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8 \xd1\x87\xd1\x91\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5, \xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8 \xd0
```

That is only a piece of it, but the theme is shown; it has colons, spaces, commas, and \n all throughout the `'bytes'` which is what type the `codecs.encode` returns. If i use `codecs` to decode it, then I get the original text back in perfect format.

if it helps, here are the functions I use to make it happen:

```
def stringToBinary(msg):
return bin(int(binascii.hexlify(msg.encode('utf-8')), 16))[2:]

def binaryToString(bNum):
    return binascii.unhexlify('%x' % (int('0b' + bNum, 2))).decode('utf-8')
```

If that is not enough, the entire file is here: http://pastebin.com/f541DpzS

EDIT: I think I'm getting that issue because the image I'm trying to hide the text in didn't have enough pixels for me to hide the complete message, so it was trying to convery the binary number to a string without all of the bits, thus throwing `binascii.Error: Odd-length string`.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Many unicode characters consist of multiple bytes, which is what you observe. And doing `binaryToString(stringToBinary(msg))` returns `msg` for me, which I can then encode to utf-8 and see the Russian text. The problem seems to be in the embedding/extracting where you don't get back the right number of bits and binascii complains. But that would make it a "why isn't my code working" kind of question, which is off topic unless reworded.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added `bNumNewLen = len(bNum) % 8;
        bNum = bNum[:len(bNum) - bNumNewLen];
        return binaryToString(bNum)` to the final return statement of my `unhide()` function and it now returns everything that the hiding was able to fit in the image.